# Jetpack Lifecycle: Fragment's View Lifecycle never reaching CREATED state, never destroyed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-lifecycle

### Problem

I recently noticed one case when in an Android app, the following exception is triggered:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles
```

It happens when registering some Observer for a viewmodel's livedata, in a fragment's `onViewCreated` callback (say fragment A):

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    myViewModel.myLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer(::onValueChanged))
    ...
}
```

It led me to figure that this happened in one specific situation, when an intent is received in the activity's `onCreate` and the decision is made to navigate to another fragment (say fragment B).

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if ("myAction" == intent?.action) {
        if (R.id.fragmentA == navController.currentDestination?.id) {
            navController.navigate(FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB())
        }
    }
}
```

If the user navigates back from that fragment B to fragment A, then that `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

### Investigation

After logging what happened in terms of lifecycle, I realised that the fragment A's `viewLifecycleOwner`'s lifecycle state is `INITIALIZED` when the fragment registers an observer for the LiveData.
This matches [what the documentation recommends](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created_and_view_initialized):

> ... The getViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData() is then updated with the newly INITIALIZED LifecycleOwner corresponding with the fragment's view. The onViewCreated() lifecycle callback is also called at this time.
>
> This is the appropriate place to set up the initial state of your view, to start observing LiveData instances whose callbacks update the fragment's view ...

However, when the activity controls the navigation from its `onCreate` callback, the fragment view's lifecycle never reaches the `STARTED` state, nor does it go downward to `DESTROYED` when the fragment B is displayed. So, going back from fragment B to fragment A, the previous lifecycle owner observes the LiveData and the new lifecycle owner of the fragment tries to observe it too, throwing the exception.

[EDIT] I kept trying to figure the changes that could have triggered this exception. I ran the code with versions `2.5.1` and `2.6.0` of `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` and I could find that the exception is triggered with version `2.6.0` (and `2.6.1`) but not with version `2.5.1`. I also added logs on the fragment callbacks and found that `onViewCreated` is called with both versions:

```
onCreateView: Fragment view is INITIALIZED
onViewCreated: Fragment view is INITIALIZED
onDestroyView: Fragment view is INITIALIZED
```

[/EDIT]

I also logged when a user navigates "manually" to another fragment and the fragment view's lifecycle goes from `INITIALIZED` to `CREATED` downward to `DESTROYED`.

### Questions

A couple questions arise: Can the lifecycle go from `INITIALIZED` directly to `DESTROYED` state? Or is it a mistake on my side that it doesn't go downward?

If it's not, what is the correct practice? Should the LiveData be observed later, once the lifecycle reaches the `CREATED` state?

Or is it that the activity shouldn't navigate to another fragment this early? Should it wait for the fragment to display a view before navigating away (obviously it's not ideal for the user experience)?

Comment: It seems like you are using the `<fragment>` tag in your activity XML. Do you see the same issue if you use `FragmentContainerView`? There is a reason why there's a Lint error specifically not to use the `<fragment>` tag ever.

Comment: It's a good point, I checked and the activity has a  `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` nested inside a `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`. The FragmentContainerView is used to host a `NavHostFragment`.

Comment: If you are using a `FragmentContainerView`, then your fragment is absolutely not going to get to `onViewCreated` before your `navigate` call in `onCreate` of your activity fires.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I kept trying to figure it out. I added logs on `onViewCreated` and it's triggered (you can see my edit). Also this happens only with versions `2.6.x` of the Jetpack lifecycle library. Following your hints about FragmentContainerView, I'm also wondering if the fact that the app uses View Binding can have an impact on the lifecycle?

Comment: What version of Lifecycle use is never going to change fragment's behavior. Again, a Fragment using `FragmentContainerView` is never, ever, ever going to get `onViewCreated` before the Activity's `onCreate()` completes. If you're seeing something different and you've confirmed that using [Fragment's debug logging](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/debugging#fm-logging), you should [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460964) that includes a sample project that reproduces that.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks I'm going to use the fragmentmanager debug logging to figure what's wrong with the fragment management

Comment: We tracked back the issue to be caused because the `Observer` class in the `lifecycle-livedata-core:2.6.0` has been converted from java to kotlin. This issue can be forced by adding the below code with 2.6.0 version.

https://gist.github.com/saran-epifi/0351e8440041a3a71702a40fa4330938

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a definitive answer but I see two ways to solve the issue.

One is to downgrade the jetpack lifecycle library, specifically `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx`, to `2.5.1`.

The other is to navigate to other Fragments from the activity's `onStart` callback.